# sed behaves differently when getting script from file

Tags: sed, matching

I need to extract strings that may contain the `\n` sequence from a file.
Note that in this case `\n` is *not* a newline, but simply the sequence of two characters: a backslash followed by a lower-case `n`.
As an example, if I type:

```
echo garbage "useful \n string" garbage | sed -e s/.*\(\"[^\"]*\"\).*/\1/
```

the result is correctly:

```
"useful \n string"
```

If instead I save the sed command to a file (`b.txt`) and type:

```
 echo garbage "useful \n string" garbage | sed -f b.txt
```

which should do the same thing, instead I don't see any match, and the result is:

```
garbage "useful \n string" garbage
```

Note that the file contains just the `sed` command; the input string, still comes from the stdin.

I am using GNU sed version 4.2.1 in a Windows 10 command line window.
Any suggestion?

Comment: To clarify the strange behavior, I need to add that if I remove the \n sequence from the string everything works fine even if the command comes from a file.
It looks like that the presence of a backslash causes the difference

Comment: On Unix, I'd be encouraging you to enclose the command in single quotes when on the command line, which might allow you to lose some of the backslashes (specifically, those in front of the double quotes).  I'm not sure which shell you're using on Windows and how that handles (mangles) the command.  One way to test might be `echo s/.*\(\"[^\"]*\"\).*/\1/` to show what `sed` sees.  In the file, I think you should remove the backslashes before the double quotes.  One of the tricky parts of handling regular expressions on command lines is understanding what the shell is doing to your regex.

Answer (score 2):

Your quoting and escape sequences look suspicious try this:

```
$ echo 'garbage "useful \n string" garbage' | sed 's/.*\("[^"]*"\).*/\1/'
"useful \n string"
$ cat b.txt
s/.*\("[^"]*"\).*/\1/
$ echo 'garbage "useful \n string" garbage' | sed -f b.txt
"useful \n string"
```

Answer (score 0):

use pair `''` and `""` correctly and `-E` instead of `-e` option in gnu sed,

```
$ echo 'garbage "useful \n string" garbage' | sed -E 's/.*("[^"]*").*/\1/'
"useful \n string"

$ cat b.txt
s/.*("[^"]*").*/\1/

$ echo 'garbage "useful \n string" garbage' | sed -Ef b.txt
"useful \n string"
```